# What does "JSON standard only allows one top level value"?

Tags: json, intellij-idea

In my IntelliJ editor, I have a test.json file as below. The second json record displays an error message "Json standard only allows one top-level value". But this is a valid JSON file, right? How to get rid of this annoying message?

```
{"reviewerID": "A2XVJBSRI3SWDI", "asin": "0000031887", "reviewerName": "abigail", "helpful": [0, 0], "title": "Ballet Dress-Up Fairy Tutu", "url": "https://www.amazon.com/dp/0000031887", "brand": "Boutique Cutie", "reviewText": "Perfect red tutu for the price. I baught it as part of my daughters Halloween costume and it looked great on her.", "overall": 5.0, "summary": "Nice tutu", "unixReviewTime": 1383523200, "reviewTime": "11 4, 2013"}
{"reviewerID": "A2G0LNLN79Q6HR", "asin": "0000031887", "reviewerName": "aj_18 \"Aj_18\"", "helpful": [1, 1], "title": "Ballet Dress-Up Fairy Tutu", "url": "https://www.amazon.com/dp/0000031887", "brand": "Boutique Cutie", "reviewText": "This was a really cute tutu the only problem is that it was super short on my 5 yr old daughter. Other than that it was really adorable.", "overall": 4.0, "summary": "Really Cute but rather short.", "unixReviewTime": 1337990400, "reviewTime": "05 26, 2012"}
```

Comment: Both are valid JSON structures. Combined, they are not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to combine them as [ {Obj 1}, {Obj 2} ] if you want to use them in the same json file. Otherwise the json file will be containing two dictionary objects and it can only have one top level object.

Comment: If it is invalid, why is my code works in parsing the file: "JSONObject doc = new JSONObject(docString);"? This perfectly works.

Comment: By works perfectly, does it parse both objects when they are in the same file?

Comment: Yes, I can parse the entire file, which contains many {} objects like above.

Comment: That's odd. Most parsers are designed to handle only one top level object per file, be it a list or a dictionary. If it handles multiple {} objects, those objects must be subset of another object.

Comment: Another note is that many API's will check a json they receive to make sure the GET request hasn't been truncated. If you have two objects and the GET request truncates after the first object, the json would be valid but you will be missing data. Limiting to 1 top-level object per json file is a feature.